# Gremlin- How to compute percentage of vertices with a certain property

Tags: gremlin, graph-traversal, datastax-studio

I am trying to use a single gremlin query to determine the percentage of vertices that satisfy a certain predicate, but I'm having trouble storing and propagating the computed values.

Say I want to compute the percentage of all vertices with label "A" that have an outgoing edge with label "B".  I can print out the number of vertices with label "A", a well as the number of vertices with an outgoing edge with label "B" in the same query:

```
g.V().limit(1).project("total","withEdgeB")
 .by(g.V().hasLabel("A").count())
 .by(g.V().hasLabel("A").match(__.as("a").outE("B").inV()).dedup().count())
```

This gives me the two relevant values: `total` and `withEdgeB`.  How do I propagate and calculate with those values?

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
g.V().limit(1).project("total","withEdgeB","percentage")
 .by(g.V().hasLabel("A").count().as("totalA"))
 .by(g.V().hasLabel("A").match(__.as("a").outE("B").inV()).dedup().count().as("totalWithEdgeB"))
 .by(totalWithEdgeB / totalA)
```

So my question is, how can I access the values `totalA` and `totalWithEdgeB` in the third `by()` statement?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would use some simple calculations. Using the modern graph, find all `person` vertices with outgoing `created` edges:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
           choose(outE('created'),
                    constant(1),
                    constant(0)).fold().
           project('total','withCreated','percentage').
             by(count(local)).
             by(sum(local)).
             by(mean(local))
==>[total:4,withCreated:3,percentage:0.75]
```